# Get list of available launch URI protocols from a Metro/Windows Store app using C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, uri, launch

I have a Metro/Windows Store App written in C#.  Is there a way to get a list of all the available launch URIs on a user's PC/device?  I'm referring to the URI's and their protocols that result in the launch of various apps like Skype, Outlook, etc.  In other words, the URI's that can be used by an app to launch another like when an app launches the E-mail client currently installed to prompt the user send an E-mail to someone, or launches the browser with a given URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the list of available URIs](http://peterfoot.net/CategoryView,category,WindowsStore.aspx). However, you can't request this list, you can try to launch URI and the system will launch it or ask the user to find the app that match this URI in the Windows Store.